# Can't import SVG in React from Webpack bundle

Tags: reactjs, svg, webpack

I have a React app that imports components from an own library of components. The library of components is a .js bundle created with Webpack.
The component that I am importing, imports another file which imports SVG files.

Original non-bundled file which imports SVGs:

```
import React from "react";
import {ShoppingBag32} from '@carbon/icons-react';
import {ReactComponent as OwnIcon} from "../design/icons/OwnIcon.svg";

const foo = {
    shop: <ShoppingBag32/>,
    ownIcon: <OwnIcon/>,
};
export default foo;
```

The `@carbon/icons-react` icons which are precompiled in their own plain JS bundle, work fine. But my own SVG fails to work.
I get:

```
Warning: React.createElement: type is invalid -- expected a string (for built-in components) or a
class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component
from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.
```

The stack trace of the warning leads to the line in the bundle where `ownIcon` is defined. You can see that the working icon of the 3rdparty bundle points to a `ShoppingBag32` key, and my own SVG points to a `ReactComponent` key.

```
var foo = {
  shop: /*#__PURE__*/react__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_2___default.a.createElement(_carbon_icons_react__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__["ShoppingBag32"], null),
  ownIcon: /*#__PURE__*/react__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_2___default.a.createElement(_design_icons_SolarPanel32_svg__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1__["ReactComponent"], null)
};
```

Any ideas on how fix the SVG import?

**EDIT**

I found out a workaround, the `img` tag can be used with the SVG path as source. But I don't like this solution because I would like the entire SVG markup to be rendered in the DOM instead of an `img` tag.

```
import React from "react";
import {ShoppingBag32} from '@carbon/icons-react';
import OwnIcon from "../design/icons/OwnIcon.svg";

const foo = {
    shop: <ShoppingBag32/>,
    ownIcon: <img src={OwnIcon}/>,
};
export default foo;
```

Comment: Your svg is just a static file but you are trying to import a react component from it. SVG is similar to a jpeg or other image file, not a javascript module like the icons-react module you are importing before that.

Comment: @JacobBotha And how do I import this static SVG file as SVG component?

Comment: Duenna's answer show's how to import a static file.

Comment: @JacobBotha I've already commented his anwer.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the default create react app, you will need to reference your SVG as follows:

`import OwnIcon from "../design/icons/OwnIcon.svg";`

The reason it is like `import {ShoppingBag32} from '@carbon/icons-react';` for carbon is because it is referenced as an export in that package as opposed to locally which webpack needs a name for the default export of an image.

Comment: The SVG is imported in a React based Storybook, which I dont know if create-react-app runs under the hood, but I see `"react-scripts": "2.1.8"` as dependency. When I import the SVG with `import OwnIcon ..` I receive warning `react-dom.development.js:88 Warning: <static/media/OwnIcon.14b929d2.svg /> is using incorrect casing. Use PascalCase for React components, or lowercase for HTML elements.`, and the page becomes all white (page crashes), before I even bundle the component for importing it in the other React app.